# mouseMove in canvas not working in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox, mousemove

the following code is used to move an element within an HTML canvas. Works great in chrome, edge, safari, opera, but doesn't work in Firefox 61.0.1.
BoxPosX and BoxPosY are used to place the element on the canvas.
Any ideas? I'm confounded.

```
function windowToCanvas(canvas1, xx, yy) {
    var bbox = canvas1.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { xx: xx ,
         yy: yy - bbox.top  * (canvas1.height / bbox.height)
    };
}

canvas1.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e){
if (event.comesFromScrollable==false){
    event.preventDefault();
    }
var loc = windowToCanvas(canvas1, e.clientX, e.clientY);
boxPosX = loc.xx;
boxPosY = loc.yy;
});
```

Comment: Firefox did not implement (yet) the non-standard (yet) global `window.event` monstruosity. Since you are naming this Event `e` from the callback argument, you can simply use `e` instead.

Comment: Thank you... these previous answers solved my problem. I should spend more time searching for the answers... two hours weren't enough. Thank you, again, Kaiido.